# Importing weights from csv file:Layer weight shape (672, 7) not compatible with provided weight shape (1, 1, 672, 7)

Tags: python, keras

I'm writing Deep learning network in Keras, previously tested in Matlab. To avoid doing all the learning, I exported weights and biases of the final layer in Matlab as the .csv file, and want to use them in my network - so my network would just test score based on given weights, instead of whole learning.

Code:

```
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'tensorflow'
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Input
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
#from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing import image

print("\n")
print("\n")
trained_weights = []
trained_bias = []

trained_weights = np.loadtxt('Weights.csv', delimiter=';')
trained_bias = np.loadtxt('Bias.csv', delimiter=';')

network_weights = np.array([[trained_weights]])
network_bias = np.array([[trained_bias]])
network_outputs = np.array([['a','c','d','e','f','g','h']])

# Load test image
img = load_img('note_a.png')
note = image.img_to_array(img)
#note = np.expand_dims(note, axis=0)
note = np.reshape(note, [1, 50, 30, 3])

# Model architecture
model = Sequential()

# Layer 1
model.add(Convolution2D(12, (6, 6), batch_size=1, input_shape=(50, 30, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))

# Layer 2
model.add(Convolution2D(24, (6, 6), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))

# Layer 3
model.add(Convolution2D(48, (6, 6), activation='relu'))

model.add(Flatten())

layer2=Dense(7, weights=[network_weights, network_bias], activation='softmax')
model.add(layer2)

model.summary()
print("\n")
print("\n")

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

#model.fit((note,network_outputs), batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1)
#score = model.evaluate(note, network_outputs)
```

I was trying to use

```
model.set_weights([network_outputs])
```

but it seems like it assigns a weights only to my first layer of network, so I just assigned weights to final layer. Result is the following error:

> ValueError: Layer weight shape (672, 7) not compatible with provided weight shape (1, 1, 672, 7)

And this is quite confusing for me. How, by doing *weights=[network_weights, network_bias]* I get 4 dimensions? Is it because network_weights has dimensions [1,672], and network_bias=[1,7], which makes [1,1,672,7]?

And how I can properly resize this weights parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.array([[trained_weights]])` creates an array out of your data surrounded by 2 empty dimensions, so your final shape is (1, 1, x, y). Same for your trained_bias. Applying `[network_weights, network_bias]` does again surround your 2 arrays with a dimension, which does obviously not match.

I think you just need to clean all the unnecessary surroundings by using something like:

```
weights=[trained_weights, trained_bias]
```

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept my answer, if it helped.